# How to do a "sticky" button that deploys a menu in Angular?

Tags: css, angular

I'm looking for a way to do something like the button of this page:

https://www.zendesk.com/

In the lower right corner, there is a "Get help" button that opens a chat menu that is also sticky. I want to put in the button dynamic info (the number of tasks the user has to do) and when clicked, It would show more information about the remain tasks.

Is there some way to achieve this with Angular?

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like this?

```js
function myFunction(){
  btn.style.display = "none";
  container.style.display = "block"
}
```

```css
.parent{
  position:fixed;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
}
#container{
  height:150px;
  width:150px;
  background-color:red;
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <button id="btn" onclick="myFunction()">click</button>
  <div id="container">containerr</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want something that works as the button in the example web. A button that is always visible in each view although the user does scroll. Like a sticky nav bar, but as a button in the right side. I think this i can achive this using CSS tricks, but I was wondering if exists a Angular plugin or widget that achieve it more "beautiful", for example, including animation to deploy the panel.